# SQL Server CE Notification Services

Tags: notifications, sql-server-ce

I've been looking for a while but without finding any real answer. I'm trying to build an application which uses SQL Server CE for portability purposes, and I need to trigger an event when the database is updated. Is there anyway to do that, like using Notification Services for SQL Server CE?

Thanks

Comment: Since SQL Server CE really isn't a **server** (despite the name), but an "embedded" database in your application, there's no provision for these kinds of services, I'm afraid. You'll have to poll your database table(s) at regular intervals to detect changes, and then react to changes happening....

Comment: I implemented a very "lightweight" polling mechanism some time ago, let me know if you are interested, and I will try to dig it out.

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, that would be super!

Answer (score 0):

This is start of a class to do lightweight polling, requires the watched table to have an IDENTITY column:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

/// <summary>
/// Sql Compact query notification class
/// </summary>
public sealed class SqlCeDependency : IDisposable 
{
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    private Int64 lastUsedIdentity = Int64.MinValue;
    private Int64 currentIdentity = Int64.MinValue;

    private SqlCeConnection conn;

    private string tableToWatch;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the underlying table changes.
    /// Initial support only for Inserts
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler OnChange;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SqlCeDependency"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableToWatch">The table to watch.</param>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    public SqlCeDependency(string tableToWatch, string connectionString)
    {
        this.tableToWatch = tableToWatch;
        StartTimer(20, connectionString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SqlCeDependency"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableToWatch">The table to watch.</param>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The SQL Compact connection string.</param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in seconds.</param>
    public SqlCeDependency(string tableToWatch, string connectionString, int interval)
    {
        this.tableToWatch = tableToWatch;            
        StartTimer(interval, connectionString);
    }

    private void CheckDependency(string tableToWatch)
    {
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT AUTOINC_NEXT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{0}' AND AUTOINC_NEXT IS NOT NULL", tableToWatch);

            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("IDENTITY column is required on watched table");
            }
            else
            {
                lastUsedIdentity = (Int64)obj;
            }
            if (currentIdentity == Int64.MinValue)
            {
                currentIdentity = lastUsedIdentity;
            }                
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer(int interval, string connectionString)
    {
        timer.Interval = interval * 1000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckDependency(tableToWatch);
        if (lastUsedIdentity != currentIdentity)
        {
            currentIdentity = lastUsedIdentity;
            if (OnChange != null)
            {
                OnChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasChanges { get; set; }


    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```